# XML file encoding format "utf-8" VS "UTF-8"?

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8

When the XML file was convert to ASCII. It is different values for user at the three characters of `utf` and `UTF`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I tried to create a new xml file with vs2005. `utf-8` form file generated by default.

which one is a more standard definition?  thanks.

Comment: Since lowercase letters are more common, `utf-8` will probably take up very slightly less space when compressed.

Comment: @Zaz Yes, lowercase compresses better https://encode.ru/threads/1889-gzthermal-pseudo-thermal-view-of-Gzip-Deflate-compression-efficiency

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The [IANA character set registry says](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets):

> no distinction is made between use of
>   upper and lower case letters.

But that page, [the XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/), and [unicode.org](http://unicode.org/resources/utf8.html) are consistent about capitalizing UTF-8.

Comment: @dan04. I would like to mark your reply as the answer. Thanks for the useful links. 

@All, Because I need convert the whole xml file to ASCII format and compare the ASCII body .... That's why I care the **upper and lower case letters.**. thank you all.

Comment: additionally, Googling `charset utf-8 uppercase|lowercase bug|solved` turns up quite a number of bug rapports that were solved/circumvented by using uppercase `UTF-8` while I found no rapports (within one evening of googling this subject) where a problem could be solved changing uppercase to lowercase. Afflicted software included Apache xerces (MacOS X), jsp, jetty (breaking AWS S3 signatures, see: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19430) and numerous others. Based on this on could make a argument that uppercase UTF-8 charset enjoys better compatibility (especially with legacy tools).

Comment: I confirm UTF-8 (uppercase). I get bad encoded results with lowercase characters when using it in MVC CORE 3.1...

Answer (score 17):

From the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charencoding):

"XML processors SHOULD match character encoding names in a case-insensitive way"

This indicates that you can use upper case or lower case or even mixed case if you wish. However, the specification uses "UTF-8" in all its examples so for consistency I'd go with that.

Answer (score 16):

For those interested in the gory details - including links to some of the related standards and precedents - I blogged a couple of years ago about [Case-Sensitivity of UTF-8 in XML Declarations](http://blog.codingoutloud.com/2009/04/08/is-utf-8-case-sensitive-in-xml-declaration/).

Answer (score 7):

In my experience (which is primarily with .NET), character set identifiers are treated as case-insensitive, so `UTF-8` and `utf-8`, as well as `Utf-8` or any other variation thereof, always mean the same thing. This would also be the case for other character sets, such as `ISO-8859-1` (Latin 1), etc. The casing should not matter, as case is not a meaninful factor in such an identifier.

I do extensive work with web services across multiple platforms, and I have never really seen a "standard" form used. I've seen every variation of a variety of character sets...often different variations from a single business partner.

Answer (score 6):

Upper-case is the de-facto standard. It should still work with any combination of case, however.